# manageprofiles.sh can't create DEPLOYMENT MANAGER

Tags: linux, deployment, websphere

My goal is to create a Deployment Manager profile in my Websphere on Linux.
Reading tons of documentation pages gives just two methods:

1) using X GUI application WAS_root/bin/ProfileManagement/pmt.sh

In this case, according to manuals, i should choose Management option, click "Next" and choose Deployment Manager server type.
Actually when i run pmt.sh in my WAS installation there is no option to choose Deployment Manager in Management section and only one profile type that i'm able to create  is AdminAgent.

2) using manageprofiles.sh script under WAS_root/bin directory.
The manuals say that i can use *-serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER* option in order to create deployment manager profile.
Actually when i run the script:

```
./manageprofiles.sh -create -templatePath ../profileTemplates/management/ -ServerType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER -isDefault -profileName dmgr -adminUserName websphere -adminPassword websphere1
```

I get the following message:

> The following validation errors were present with the command line
>   arguments:
>           serverType: The value for this parameter must be within this set of values [ADMIN_AGENT]

That means that i don't have the ability to create Deployment Manager at all.
Please advise what steps i can perform to be able to install Deploy Manager except erase my WAS installation and install it from scratch once again.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have standalone aka base edition of WebSphere Application Server. To create Deployment Manager you need Network Deployment edition.

Unfortunately you will have to install it from scratch from different installation files (from ND, not base or developers edition).